# How the money can be destroyed when some country or corporation defaults

Tags: money-supply

As far as i know for every dollar/euro/yen in the money supply pool there is a corresponding IOU in a bank or central bank. My question is how the system can track down and withdraw the excessive money supply (i.e. the amount of dollars dollars corresponding to a specific defaulted IOU) when the liable party for the IOU defaults.

Comment: Sorry if it was offtopic but I didn't know where else to ask. Anyways I want to thank Andy for the answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an Economics question, I guess.

You are not quite correct naming government debt IOU (that stands for I Owe You and was mainly used in California as a desperate attempt to recover from the recent financial crisis).

So in order to control M3, central banks can use three main tools of the monetary policy:

1. Changing reserve ratio
2. Changing Interest Rate
3. Manipulating government bonds

So to reduce M3:

1. Increase the reserve ratio - so that banks have to hold more reserves against deposits thus reducing availability of money in the market.
2. By increasing interest rate private banks are discouraged from borrowing thus again reducing money supply.
3. Selling government securities (to private banks) would also decrease available reserves at banks thus reduce money supply in the economy.

This is a very short answer. In practice things are much more complicated, but I hope this answers your question.